# Java is installed, in listing, but execution produces "./java: No such file or directory"

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I just ran the script below and it fetches and unpacks the JDK into the correct location. Problem is that every `java` command (as copied to */urs/bin*) gives errors. I then double check by going into the JDK install directory by means of `cd` (I am now in JDK/bin) and type : `./java -version` and get : `./java: No such file or directory`, but `java` is there! `ls -l` on the JDK shows that all `java` clients are inside the *bin*.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Author: Yucca Nel http://thejarbar.org
#Will restart system
#Modify these variables as needed...
tempWork=/tmp/work
locBin=/usr/local/bin
javaUsrLib=/usr/lib/jvm

sudo mkdir -p $javaUsrLib
mkdir -p $tempWork
cd $tempWork

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of JDK...
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u2-b13/jdk-7u2-linux-i586.tar.gz

#Extract the download
tar -zxvf $tempWork/*

#Move it to where it can be found...

sudo mv -f $tempWork/jdk1.7* $javaUsrLib/

sudo ln -f -s $javaUsrLib/jdk1.7*/bin/* /usr/bin/
sudo rm -rf $tempWork
#Update this line to reflect newer versions of JDK...
export JAVA_HOME="$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_02"

if ! grep "JAVA_HOME=$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_02" /etc/environment
then
    echo "JAVA_HOME=$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_02"| sudo tee -a /etc/environment
fi

sudo /sbin/reboot

exit 0
```

Running `ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java` gives me : `yucca@yucca-VirtualBox:~$ 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 yucca yucca 5654 2011-11-17 22:38 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java`

also ran: `file /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/bin` with an output of :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/bin: directory
```

Comment: Rebooting to install java? That's not the "Unix Way".

Comment: @MarcB If the user closes the terminal, the environment (with Java) is lost no? My script worked a few days ago and when I run with bash -x I can see the jdk being unpacked in full...

Comment: No, the `/etc/environment` stuff ensures that the JAVA_HOME var will show up in all new shells. The only reason I can think of for the reboot is to ensure that all 'old' currently-running jvms are terminated.

Comment: Please show the output from `ls -l java`.

Comment: @MarcB I edited script and remounted it and ran it without the reboot... and still the same problem?

Comment: @ShiDoiSi 'yucca@yucca-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java'  Gives:
'-rwxr-xr-x 1 yucca yucca 5654 2011-11-17 22:38 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/java'

Comment: You might want to put that into the question instead of a comment, for better readability.

Comment: Could you also please run the `file` command on the java-binary? Are you by chance on a funky architecture?

Comment: On the binary, not the directory...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're running on a 64bit system without a 32bit runtime environment.

Assuming ubuntu/debian issue:

```
apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Or you should install the 64bit version of the package into this VM (which is probably the best solution).

The error message is coming from the run-time linker/loader. if you do a `readelf -l java` you will find a line like:

```
 [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
```

Which is what you expect for a 32bit application, and you probably don't have the 32bit environment installed - check with an ls -l of that `program interpreter`.

and example for a 64bit program would look like (your system may vary):

```
 [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

If this is not the case, and you do have the 32bit libc installed, you can try an `ldd java`, which will give a listing like:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76ef000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76b3000)
libjli.so => /home/bubba/java/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/./../jre/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so (0xf769f000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf7699000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf751f000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76f0000)
```

if there are lines saying `not found` then you should add pagkages providing that, but as you can see from this `ldd` all the dependencies are core libraries that should be present on practically all linux systems.

Comment: Thank you. This is what happened... I am in the process of doing a set of tutorials showing how I set up my development environment. I now noticed that the version I am using of Ubuntu in VirtualBox was AMD 64 bit and I am on Intel chip. Prior to this the script worked, but I notice the new guest I did yesterday is from the wrong Ubuntu image.

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP and it was solved by running `apt-get install libc6-i386`. I wonder if there may be additional issues with 32-bit JDK 7 on 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: @Petesh having the same problem, but with an arm cpu. I wonder if there are libs for arm..

Comment: @Eugene You're on a Linux ARM platform? What does `file java` report? What does `readelf -l java | grep interp` report? Does that interpreter exist? Android uses a different interpreter `/system/bin/linker`, and if you're on Android then I don't know of a compiled JDK for Android.

Comment: @Petesh not yet android. But jdk 7 works fine. All I had to do is a sudo apt-get install libc6-* (around 40MB)

Comment: Doesn't work on aarch64 (ARMv8).  I wonder what the solution is for that architecture?

Comment: @hoosierEE did you download the ARM64 version of the jdk? That would be an easier approach - there is an arm64 version of the Oracle JDK.

Comment: @Petesh That's what I tried. The only JRE I got to work was openjdk.  Oracle java8 sitting right in front of me, `readelf -l java` looks fine, yet `java -version` gives "file not found".

Comment: @hoosierEE it's not really practical to try to solve the issue over comments; but this 'file not found' is because the run-time interpreter just isn't there. What does `file $(readelf -l /usr/bin/java | sed -n 's/.*interpreter: \([^]]*\)\]/\1/p')` yield (this extracts the run-time interpreter and runs file on it)? Different ARM platforms have different run-time interpreters - I believe the Oracle one is looking for `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the

> bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

The issue was I installed the `i586` version of Java on a `x86_64` Debian.

The fix: I removed it and install the `x64` version of Java. Everything is working fine now.