# No such file or directory Java Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04

I get the message no such file or directory as you can see in the image below:
[image]

As you can see I do have a `bin` folder in `/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin`

In my `.bashrc` file I have the following contents:

```
#Java HOME directory setup
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_144
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

I also came across the following 2 questions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/207552/no-such-file-or-directory-when-invoking-java

[Java is installed, in listing, but execution produces "./java: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081962/java-is-installed-in-listing-but-execution-produces-java-no-such-file-or-d/9082947#9082947)

And I had followed Petesh answer to use the `ldd java` command to see which packages I´m missing. But as you can see in the image below it didn´t worked out:
[image]

However I can see that both `java -version` and `ldd --version` commands are working. I´m using a 64-bit notebook. Can someone maybe help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

`java` appears to be correctly installed, you can run "java" with

```
$ java <MYOPTIONS>
```

Your **error** is trying to execute your "PATH" with `$PATH` if you want to display the path, you echo it. Like,

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Or, if you want to find where java is

```
$ type -path java
/usr/bin/java
```

Or, the more usual Ubuntu way

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-8-oracle                  1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on my Ubuntu, all variables were set correctly but had an error anyway. Turned out that my Ubuntu was missing some packages. Fixed with following lines

```
apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Comment: I was going insane, it was not the first time I have done this and I couldn't believe my eyes when the output of *java -version* was *No such file or directory* popped up ... while *ls -l* showed me the file was indeed there