# -bash: /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_301/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, installation

I have run `java -version` then it will display

> -bash: /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_301/bin/java: No such file or directory.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: From what you have shared, seems like JAVA_HOME is pointing to that directory, could you print JAVA_HOME and share de output?

Comment: If everything is installed correctly you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71662170/5911964